# Forward fill rows in a r data table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a large data.table in the format below

```
Name       Value     1      2     3     4     5 
A           58       1      NA    NA    NA    NA
B           47       NA     1     NA    NA    NA
C           89       NA     NA    1     NA    NA
D           68       NA     NA    NA    1     NA
E           75       NA     NA    NA    NA    1
```

I would like to forward rows of the data table to achieve below results. I know how to forward fill columns.

```
Name       Value     1      2     3     4     5 
A           58       1      1     1     1     1
B           47       NA     1     1     1     1
C           89       NA     NA    1     1     1
D           68       NA     NA    NA    1     1
E           75       NA     NA    NA    NA    1
```

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fill` in `tidyr` to fill in missing values with previous value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(3:7) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  fill(value) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider()

# # A tibble: 5 x 7
#   Name  Value   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
#   <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 A        58     1     1     1     1     1
# 2 B        47    NA     1     1     1     1
# 3 C        89    NA    NA     1     1     1
# 4 D        68    NA    NA    NA     1     1
# 5 E        75    NA    NA    NA    NA     1
```

**Note:** The output above is the same as

```
df %>% fill(3:7, .direction = "up")
```

but the logic is different. The former belongs to *"filling rows forward"* and the latter is *"filling columns backward"*. They will differ in other cases.

---

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:5, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E"), class = "factor"), Value = c(58L, 47L, 89L, 68L, 75L
), `1` = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2` = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), 
`3` = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), `4` = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA), 
`5` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 5):

data.table has it's own `nafill` function.

```
library(data.table) #v>=1.12.8
library(magrittr)

melt(dt, id = 1:2) %>% 
  .[, value := nafill(value, "locf"), by = Name] %>% 
  dcast(., ... ~ variable)

#    Name Value  1  2  3  4 5
# 1:    A    58  1  1  1  1 1
# 2:    B    47 NA  1  1  1 1
# 3:    C    89 NA NA  1  1 1
# 4:    D    68 NA NA NA  1 1
# 5:    E    75 NA NA NA NA 1
```

---

**Data**

```
dt <- fread("Name       Value     1      2     3     4     5 
A           58       1      NA    NA    NA    NA
B           47       NA     1     NA    NA    NA
C           89       NA     NA    1     NA    NA
D           68       NA     NA    NA    1     NA
E           75       NA     NA    NA    NA    1")
```

Comment: Are you afraid of a temporary variable at the cost of new dependency? :)

Comment: Jan, I don't consider magrittr as an heavy dependency and I also like the readability it provides when chaining many operations. I also don't like cluttering the global environment, so I find it as the less worse option. If I would install the whole tidyverse only in order to use `mutate` instead `$` I would agree with you definitely :)